# Inheriting Top Link Navigation Programmatically

Tags: top-link-bar, inheritance

In my SharePoint 2010 solution I am creating Top Link Navigation programmatically ( on feature activation). Now on other feature activation I am adding a subsite to my site. I want my sub site to inherit the parent site's TLN. But I didn't find any parameter for this in the following method e.g. 
    parent.Webs.Add(siteURL, siteTitle, "", Convert.ToUInt32(LOCALE_ID_ENGLISH), siteTemplate,      false, false);

How can I inherit Top Link Navigation in my sub site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit the navigation via:

```
SPWeb web = parent.Web.Add(/*params....*/);
web.Navigation.UseShared = true;
```

Use it just after you have created the site.

More Information: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation.useshared.aspx)